# WPF textbox binding not working when using stringformat

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Here is my problem:

I had a textbox that was using textbox preview and doing some validation on the text entered. The textbox is bound to a double property. Originally when a user entered a number with a decimal it would crash because when it is updating after every key stroke when the number was 1. it was automatically changed to 1 (removing the decimal) and when adding the next number after the decimal it would think the position to insert the new character is position 3 but since the decimal was automatically removed there is no longer a position 3  it errors out. I fixed this by adding `StringFormat={}{0:d}` to the xaml. This worked fine except for the fact that when everything loads for the first time the original value no longer shows up (the value from the database). But if I remove only the StringFormat the value will load but then I have the crashing problem again.

Any ideas?

```
 <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                             Controls:TextBoxMask.NumericType="Double"
                             Text="{Binding Path=Model.Processor.BulkShiftInMilliseconds, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, StringFormat={}{0:d}}"/>
```

Comment: Did you look at the Visual Studio output window? you can usually find valuable information to troubleshoot binding errors in there.

Comment: I did:  'StringFormat' converter failed to convert value '1' (type 'Double');

Answer (score -1):

Tested, body must be 30 characters

```
StringFormat={}{0}
```

Comment: That allows the textbox to populate but I'm back to the issue of it dropping the decimal place in the code behind, when it does the input text validation.

Comment: Found the root of my issue. See the following link: