# Dot in TextBox in XAML using binding

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a problem almost the same as described in 
[WPF textbox binding not working when using stringformat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144461/wpf-textbox-binding-not-working-when-using-stringformat)
I have slider and textbox. Textbox binded to a value property of slider with update trigger onpropertychanged in toway mode. I make check for user input in textbox, so I can only input digits or "-/+".
My problem is that I have not only integer, but also float values and I don't now how many digits will after dot, so I don't want to limit user. 
I use string format D `StringFormat=D` for that purpose, but in that case no output in TextBox visible, but I still could enter digits and it influence the slier value, but when I move slider - text disappears from textbox.

I want that value from slider was visible in textbox and I have no limits for entering digits after dot. How Can I do it?
P.S. I am using .NET 4.5.

Here is my converter:

```
class ToStringConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            return value.ToString();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            float fvalue = System.Convert.ToSingle(value.ToString(), culture);
            return fvalue;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

It displays values good, but I cannot input values - its crashes and always switch to maximum value instead of that I want to.

Here is my XAML code

```
<Page.Resources >

        <settingsManager:RoundingConverter x:Key="RoundingConverter"></settingsManager:RoundingConverter>
        <settingsManager:ToStringConverter x:Key="ToStringConverter"></settingsManager:ToStringConverter>

    </Page.Resources>

<TextBox x:Name="TextBoxFirstPersonCameraPositionX" Text="{Binding ElementName=SliderFirstPersonCameraPositionX, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, IsAsync=True, Delay=0, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource ToStringConverter}}"  
                                         Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontWeight="Normal" MaxWidth="200" MinWidth="198" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxLength="40" DataObject.Pasting="TextBoxPasting" PreviewTextInput="OnPreviewTextInput"
                                         >
                                </TextBox>
```

Comment: Sharing your current code would help others fix your problem quickly

Comment: I tried ti write my own converter, but it does not work properly:

Answer (score 0):

First, try replacing "float" and "ToSingle" by "double" and "ToDouble". Slider.Value is a double, not a float.

Then, Convert.ToSingle [might throw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/faab9yks(v=vs.110).aspx) a FormatException. You should catch and handle this exception. Also, the OverflowException, to be on the safe side. Alternatively, use [double.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.double.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead to avoid the exceptions in the first place.

Then, when converting, you [should always set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182190.aspx) a CultureInfo. You might be on a system where not a "." but a "," is used to separate the decimals.

To find out why it crashes, try the following: Debug your code, press Ctrl-Alt-E and check "Common Language Runtime Exceptions / Thrown". Then, whenever an exception is thrown, e.g. a FormatException, the debugger stops, and you can see what is happening.